# Chrome extension callback passes two values and one shows up undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, callback

Can anyone explain to me why the output is: "x is: 0 y is: undefined"??

browseraction.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {msg: "test"}, function(x,y){
    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "x is: " + x + " y is: " + y;
  });
});
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.msg == "test"){
        sendResponse(0,0);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did it work or not?

Answer (score 2):

According to

- [`chrome.tabs.sendMessage(integer tabId, any message, object options, function responseCallback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage)
- [`chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function callback)`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage)

in the `responseCallback` and `sendResponse`function, there is only one parameter which is the json response object. It is likely the extra parameter would be dropped when calling `sendResponse` ( I guess)

And as we know in JavaScript, **arguments which are not provided would become `undefined`**, that's why you get `undefined` when accessing to `y` in the callback of `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

Do not know why it doesn't work, but this should works:

browseraction.js

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {msg: "test"}, function(resp){
    document.getElementById("status").textContent = "x is: " + resp.x + " y is: " + resp.y;
  });
});
```

contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    if(request.msg == "test"){
        sendResponse({x: 0, y: 0});
    }
});
```

You should use textContent and not innerHTML.